# Firefox: `transform: translate (%)` plus `filter: drop-shadow` makes the text blurry

Tags: html, css, firefox, filter, dropshadow

When I add `transform: translate (x%, y%)` and `filter: drop-shadow (...)` the text gets blurred in Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

I have managed to test only on Firefox for Mac, @abney317 tested on Windows and also identified the problem.

```js
document.querySelector('.bt').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let a = document.querySelector('.a');

    if (a.classList.contains('a--shadow')) {
        a.classList.remove('a--shadow');
    } else {
        a.classList.add('a--shadow');
    }
})
```

```css
.a {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    background:#fff;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

.a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-left: .5rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom: .5rem solid #fff;
    top: -.5rem;
    left: .5rem;
}

.a--shadow {
    filter: drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, .9) 0 0 0.125rem);
}
```

```html
<button class="bt">Toogle drop-shadow filter</button>

<div class="a">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I do see this issue on Windows also. Guess it's an issue with how Firefox renders elements that have a filter applied to them.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the description stating that the problem was also seen in Windows.